# Mounting a map on a server through a different server

Tags: mount, directory

First of all, my excuses, I could not find the question here anywhere. The thing is, I want to mount a map on server 1, and server 1 is only accessible throughout server 2. I'm on pc 1, which can only ssh to server 2. How would I mount the map on server 1?

With regards,
Jelmer

Comment: Your topology is: server1 -> server2 -> pc1? PC1 is not on same network like server1? Server2 have two nic, one in network with pc1 and another with nic in network with server1?

Comment: pc1 can acces server 1. Server 1 can acces server 2.  pc1 cannot acces server 2 because it is a different network.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can add some `iptables` rules on server2 and pc will can connect to server1.

Server2

Enable traffic forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then set `iptables`

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \ -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Try from `PC1` to connect "directly" to `Server1`

Comment: I cannot do so, since I don't own the server. It is a calculation cluster hosted by the university.